# Empty anchor tags

Tags: symfony, twig

I am trying to style a template and I have added some anchor tags using twig:

`<a href="{{ path('brain_labs_app') }}">`

This works fine except that if I inspect my page then it also inserts `<a></a>` and it does it at odd places.

**Source:**

```
<div class="menu-bar">
    <div class="nav-block">
        <div class="nav-block-icon">
            <a href="{{ path('brain_labs_app') }}">
            <img width="26" height="28" src="{{ asset('bundles/brainlabsapp/images/favicon.png') }}"/>
            <span>Home</span>
            <a/>
        </div>
</div>
    <div class="nav-block">
        <div class="nav-block-icon">
            <a href="{{ path('clients') }}">
            <img width="26" height="28" src="{{ asset('bundles/brainlabsapp/images/clients.png') }}"/>
            <span>Clients</span>
           </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Output:**

```
<div class="menu-bar">
    <div class="nav-block">
        <div class="nav-block-icon">
            <a href="/MichalCRM/web/app_dev.php/">
            <img width="26" height="28" src="/MichalCRM/web/bundles/brainlabsapp/images/favicon.png">
            <span>Home</span>
            </a>
            <a></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a></a>
    <div class="nav-block">
        <a></a>
        <div class="nav-block-icon">
            <a></a>
            <a href="/MichalCRM/web/app_dev.php/client/">
            <img width="26" height="28" src="/MichalCRM/web/bundles/brainlabsapp/images/clients.png">
            <span>Clients</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<a/>` should be `</a>`. anchor tags are **NOT** self-closing.

Comment: 1 typo does not account for 3 extra `<a></a>` in different places.